# Is this a potato plant?

Tags: identification, seedlings, potatoes

I planted 12 pieces of potatoes ~2-3 weeks back and see few sprouts but don't know if they are weeds or actually the potato plants. The plants look like this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: That low lying hairyish leaf in the background on the top picture might be a potato plant.  The other is just a clover.

Comment: Did you plant 12 potatoes, or, parts of potatoes with eyes? Were they seed potatoes, and how deep did you plant them? What season is it?

Comment: @GrahamChiu: I cut 3 potatoes into 12 pieces with their eyes and sprouts intact and then planted them. Officially summer just started. I read in one gardener blog suggesting to dig a hole ~4 inches deep and plant them. I think I dug little too (~5-6 inches) deep.

Comment: You could dig a little to see if they're alive. But I'd half expect at that depth they should be showing now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry, neither is a potato plant.

A potato sprout is medium to dark green (sometimes with reddish undertones just when breaking through), looks like a little whirl of wrinkly, thick leaves, then unfolds to the typical compound leaf.

[image] [image]
<sup>(click to enlarge)</sup>

The first plant in your post is probably a wood sorrel or [oxalis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxalis), the second a [clover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clover). Without flowers and more details a precise id is near impossible, but I can at least tell you that these are not your potatos.

Many gardeners would pull them up as weeds immediately, you can enjoy the flowers first, then pull before they go to seed - or use your own judgement.

Comment: The first one is definitely a oxalis, but which kind is difficult to tell without a flower. The second is either Dutch white clover or red clover. It is not one of the taller types, those have different leaves.

Comment: I got one sprout like the phone on the left :)